Как сделать сохранение ведомости в файл автоматически?
Как в 1с 8.3 11 редакции сделать автоматическое сохранение Ведомости по ценам в номенклатуре в файл в виде xlsx файла по таймеру?
В ручном режиме это сделать легко выставив нужные настройки и просто сохранить в виде файла на рабочем столе, но как те же действия сделать в автоматическом режиме?

Написать код, который по расписанию будет формировать отчет и сохранять. Это можно реализовать через внешнюю обработку, подключаемую к БСП.
Либо, попробовать настроить автоматическую рассылку отчета на email. Вроде как такое можно делать в типовых конфигурациях. А потом из почты скачивать.
Примеры:
Как настроить автоматическую рассылку отчетов и уведомлений?
Рассылка отчетов

Вот как, спасибо. Как понимаю если делать внешний обработчик, то нужно делать через конфигурации и для формирования отчёта с определёнными настройками тоже есть свой скрипт?

@Kolhun, не понял что вы хотели сказать.

В плане обработчики, например внешние, делаются через конфигурации? И если обработчик будет сохранять к примеру Ведомость по ценам в номенклатуре, шаблон для печати, колонки и прочие настройки нужно тоже как-то подтягивать?

@Kolhun, код пишется в конфигураторе. Если вы в этом не разбираетесь, обратитесь к специалисту.

Да, понял, спасибо
